# how to create a word document with all the content of several others with phpword

Tags: php, phpword

i have to make one .docx document with all the content of several .docx documents

```
foo.docx
bar.docx
foobar.docx
```

all-in-one.docx must be build like this

```
  foo.docx content
+ page break
+ bar.docx content
+ page break
+ foobar.docx content
```

PHP 7.0 | laravel 5.5 | PHPWord 0.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pull request](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/1327) that was accepted June 30 suggests the following.

Loops sections of one document and inserts it in another.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('Lorem ipsum');

// Load another document
$phpWord2 = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('lorem.docx');

// Add sections to the first document
foreach ($phpWord2->getSections() as $section) {
    $phpWord->addExistingSection($section);
}
```

So you would just basically (untested code)

```
<?php
    $documents = ['doc1.docx', 'doc2.docx', 'doc3.docx', 'doc4.docx'];
    $lastDoc = end($documents);

    $mainDoc = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    foreach($documents as $document) {
        $appendDoc = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($document);
        foreach ($appendDoc->getSections() as $section) {
            $mainDoc->addExistingSection($section);
        }

        // Add page break after every appended doc except the last one
        if($document != $lastDoc) {
            $section = $mainDoc->addSection();
            $section->addPageBreak();
        }
    }
```

Now `$mainDoc` should be ready to save.

Another possible solution is to use [DocxMerge](https://github.com/krustnic/DocxMerge). Not sure it supports adding page breaks etc though.

Comment: thanks Inquam, that work well, a pity this PR did'nt be pushed :)

Comment: precision: work for "simple" documents, seems not working for very complex dicuments with several array, text zone and other imbricated stuff

Comment: My PHPWord does not have `addExistingSection` function. Where is it?